# Calculate from a subsample N times in R

Tags: r, resampling

Consider the following data with 4 observations:

```
library(Benchmarking)
d <- data.frame(x1=c(100,200,30,500), x2=c(300,200,10,50), y=c(75,100,3000,400),  row.names = LETTERS[1:4])
e <- dea(d[c('x1', 'x2')], d$y)
mean(eff(e))
```

This gives me:

```
[1] 0.4125
```

Now I want to select `3` observations out of `d` for all 4 combinations (that is without repetition). For all these `4` combinations with `3` observations I want to calculate:

```
e <- dea(d[c('x1', 'x2')], d$y)
mean(eff(e))
```

This should give me the following average for all `4` combinations:

```
0,45   0,5   1   0,483...
```

Of these `4` average I would like to calculate the average. That gives me:

```
0.6083333
```

Can someone show me a loop/function which do all these in one?

Comment: if you want to get the same value every time you run sample you must first set the seed. `set.seed(1)` and choose a value for the seed, in this case I used 1. Then see if you get the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combn to find out all the possible line combinations, then run your loop over them:

```
row_comb = combn(1:4,3)

m = vector('numeric')

for (r in 1:4)
{
  e1 <- dea(d[row_comb[,r], c('x1', 'x2')], d$y[row_comb[,r]])
  m[r] <- mean(eff(e1))
}

mean(m)
```